# Error while creating trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am a beginner in my sql and I am a getting an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@nissue INT DEFAULT 0; set @nissue := (set issue_id from Codes
>   where code' at line 5

for the code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ai_SMS
    AFTER INSERT ON SMS
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
       DECLARE @nissue INT DEFAULT 0;
       set @nissue := (set issue_id from Codes where code=NEW.msgbody);
 IF ( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SMS_fltr AS s INNER JOIN Persons AS  p ON s.sender=p.mobile_number WHERE  s.numissue=@nissue and s.sender=NEW.sender))
       THEN
              UPDATE SMS_fltr set time=NEW.time ,code=NEW.msgbody where  numissue=@nissue and sender=NEW.sender;

       ELSE

              INSERT into SMS_fltr (sender,time,code,numissue) VAUES (NEW.sender,NEW.time,NEW.code,nissue);
       END IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to create a trigger for a table.

Can any body please tell what mistake I made and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion #1 : Don't declare it

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ai_SMS
    AFTER INSERT ON SMS
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
       set @nissue := (set issue_id from Codes where code=NEW.msgbody);
 IF ( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SMS_fltr AS s INNER JOIN Persons AS  p ON s.sender=p.mobile_number WHERE  s.numissue=@nissue and s.sender=NEW.sender))
       THEN
              UPDATE SMS_fltr set time=NEW.time ,code=NEW.msgbody where  numissue=@nissue and sender=NEW.sender;

       ELSE

              INSERT into SMS_fltr (sender,time,code,numissue) VAUES (NEW.sender,NEW.time,NEW.code,nissue);
       END IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

## Suggestion #2 : Declare it as a regular variable

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ai_SMS
    AFTER INSERT ON SMS
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
       DECLARE nissue INT DEFAULT 0;
       set nissue := (set issue_id from Codes where code=NEW.msgbody);
 IF ( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SMS_fltr AS s INNER JOIN Persons AS  p ON s.sender=p.mobile_number WHERE  s.numissue=@nissue and s.sender=NEW.sender))
       THEN
              UPDATE SMS_fltr set time=NEW.time ,code=NEW.msgbody where  numissue=@nissue and sender=NEW.sender;

       ELSE

              INSERT into SMS_fltr (sender,time,code,numissue) VAUES (NEW.sender,NEW.time,NEW.code,nissue);
       END IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

## Give it a Try !!!